# C# MongoDB Sort by Calculation

Tags: c#, mongodb

I need to sort my data by date but, I want to sort it by the today date. E.g with linq: SortBy(t => t.StartDate.Today == DateTime.Today). This query is not working and I'm looking for something like that. Is that possible with C# Driver of MongoDB? Because MongoDB sort just accepts ascending or descending by a field.

Regards

Comment: Use a WHERE then sort.

Comment: What do you mean by today's date? When you use Today at the end of DateTime Hour and Minute and second and millisecond is zero. If they are all zeroes then they are all the same and Have today's date and they have no specific place(order) in query. Explain what you mean by that please.